# Проблемы с выводом

Tags: php

**Приветствую!)** У меня почему-то не выводится текст. *Прошу помочь.*

```
// выбираем дизайн
 if(@$_GET['design']) {
    $sql = "SELECT `top`, `subject` FROM `styles` WHERE `subject`='$id_cab'";
     $res = mysql_query($sql);
     $rows = mysql_fetch_array($res);
      echo $rows[top];
}
```

Следует учесть, что в `.htaccess` прописано следующее:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cabinets/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z]+)$ cabinets.php?id=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

То есть мне нужно что в такой ссылке `cabinets/29/index` выводился самый первый код, который я указала выше. Я не знаю почему, но в пределах { } текст не выводится и текст будто из базы не достается.

Comment: сделайте роутер вместо всего этого.

Comment: не используйте расширение **mysql** :

[depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: $_GET['design'] - у вас нет, т.е. следуя из Вашего запроса вы имеете:$_GET['id'] и $_GET['page']

Comment: хм, я не вижу, что должно идти в $_GET['design'], может .htaccess получше стоит настроить?, или по другим ссылкам обращаться.

а вообще, кроме этого:

1) проверьте заходит ли вообще на эту страницу

2) проверьте, заходит ли в это условие

3) проверьте sql запрос, и попробуйте его выполнить не через php

Comment: + ошибка $rows[top]

Comment: idd, О том, что это ошибка: $rows[top], сайт меня не оповещал. И кстати работает и выводит нормально.

Comment: Ксения, ошибка заключается в том, что top - это ключ, поэтому Вам необходимо заключить его в кавычки: $rows['top']

Comment: @idd php в неstrict режиме превращает неизвестные константы в строки без оповещения.

Comment: @eicto, спасибо, проверил, действительно так!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо

```
if(@$_GET['design'])
```

пишите

```
if(isset($_GET['design']))
```

в ваших правилах RewriteRule нет ничего про design, соответственно  нет и элемента массива $_GET с ключём design

вероятно вы хотите

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id_cab=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
    $sql = "SELECT `top`, `subject` FROM `styles` WHERE `subject`='$id_cab'";
     $res = mysql_query($sql);
     while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       echo $rows['top'];
}
```

но еще раз - не используйте mysql, используйте mysqli или PDO

Comment: есть еще коды до // выбираем дизайн.... поэтому WHERE `subject`='$id_cab' прописано верно.

Comment: Но всё равно огромное спасибо)) Я решила проблему с помощью вашего кода)

Comment: У меня весь сайт построен на Mysql, я не могу вот так взять и перейти на несколько другую кодировку...

Comment: это не кодировка :) это расширение php, новый код не пишите с использованием этого расширения и все будут немного счастливее.